# Accessing the current tab with chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

I want to access a tab using a chrome extention and to able to get the HTML code from it.
Is this possible?

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Your question in not very precise. Where do you need this HTML code? What will you want to do with it?

One way to get the HTML code is to use [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). Your javascript file will be executed when the page is loaded. You can acces the dom normaly.

If you need it from the background page. There are other ways to do this. Please update your quesition and I will update this answer.